# How to change layout in controller in ZendFramework2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I found this topic and answer: [Change layout in the controller of Zend Framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9112766/2898694) :: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413957/2898694)

I am trying to do this:

```
public function loginAction() {
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin');
    }
    $this->layout('layout/login');
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Sure I have file `MODULE_DIR/view/layout/login.phtml`.

I tried to `var_dump($this->layout());` before setting layout and after it and it shows, that layout is changed after `$this->layout('layout/login');` line. But it is not.

**How to set different layout in controller?**

Also, **why I don't get any messages if layout is changed**? **Why standart layout loaded, instead of error**?

I think, I have to set up layout somewhere (like I set routes, for example). Possibly in config `['view_manager']['template_map']` by adding something like:

```
$config = array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view'
        ),        
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/login'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/login.phtml',
        ),
    ),
);
```

— like said [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573445/2898694):

> Of course you need to define those layouts, too... just check
>   Application Modules `module.config.php` to see how to define a layout.

That didn't helped me :(

### Update 1

Tried this:

```
public function loginAction() {
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin');
    }
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTemplate('layout/login');
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

as [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622039/alex) suggested. Doesn't work :'(. Same result without `return new ViewModel();` line.

You review files by yourself:

- [AdminController.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/MyZfcAdmin/src/MyZfcAdmin/Controller/AdminController.php) (loginAction)
- [module.config.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/MyZfcAdmin/config/module.config.php) (to be sure I added `layout/login` correctly

### Update 2

I tried to debug as you suggest.

I updated `__invoke` functioN:

```
public function __invoke($template = null)
{
    var_dump($template);
    die();
    if (null === $template) {
        return $this->getViewModel();
    }
    return $this->setTemplate($template);
}
```

There are some cases:

With code, you suggested:

```
$layout = $this->layout();
$layout->setTemplate('layout/login');
```

it displays NULL. So method is called, but `$template` is null variable.

With code, from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413957/2898694), I had given in the start of my post:

```
$this->layout('layout/login');
return new ViewModel();
```

It shows `string(12) "layout/login"`.

Without any code (so layout `layout/admin` loaded (default for `ZfcAdmin`), it shows: `string(12) "layout/admin"`.

If I load `/` of my site it page is loaded with standart layout (in both cases with or without `layout/layout` in module config.

### Update 3

I tried this:

```
$layout = $this->layout();
var_dump($layout->getTemplate());
$layout->setTemplate('layout/login');
var_dump($layout->getTemplate());
die();
```

in controller. It shows: `string(13) "layout/layout" string(12) "layout/login"`. So layout is changed. But standart layout `layout/layout` rendered instead of `layout/login`. :(

Comment: Your login route is a ZfcAdmin route, if you have `use_admin_layout` enabled in ZfcAdmin, there's a pretty good chance that's the issue since the listener is likely to over-write the layout you're setting in your controller action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Login route is default at the moment: url `/user/login`, route `zfcuser/login`, I didn't redifined it. I created my own controller/view in which I show widget with login form, route name is `zfcadmin/login`, url is `/admin/login`. `use_admin_layout` id

Comment: I never said you redefined the user route, I'm specifically talking about the admin route. Unless you're saying zfcadmin layout is disabled, which I can't tell from your comment, it's going to use admin layout. If it *is* enabled (it's enabled by default) you can test my theory by simply setting `'use_admin_layout' = false;` in the zfcadmin config and seeing if it has any effect.

Comment: @Crisp mhm!!! I did what you said and now layout set properly, but layout of admin panel is not set now (it's default, as in application module — `layout/layout`. I want different layout in admin module. How can I do this? Is it possible. Perhaps, like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734193/2898694) answer? Can you clarify this, if it is possible and summarize all what you said in new answer, so I can accept it? You are very close to solve my problem. Thank you. _Some grumble: oh this dependencies!!! (especially for me - noooob)_

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes, I'll write up the answer, and a possible solution too.

Comment: @Crisp. Thanks in advance. Going sleep now anyway :) I will review it tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I'll finish it up in the morning, it's late here too

Comment: @Crisp as you wish :) It would be very nice. If you need, you can find my project [here](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project).

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, busy day, hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using `ZfcAdmin` **and** have the `use_admin_layout` option enabled in that module **and** the login route you're attempting to set a layout on is a child route of ZfcAdmin, the admin layout listener is kicking in and over-writing the template you're attempting to set in your controller action.

It's perhaps easiest to disable zfcadmin layout, write your own listener and handle the specific case of login layout there. You can do that using essentially the same method that ZfcAdmin uses in Module.php with a tweak or two ...

Be sure to disable ZfcAdmin layout

```
'zfcadmin' => array(
    'use_admin_layout' => false,
),
```

then, using your module name as a config key, set up your own version of the same config ...

```
'myzfcadmin' => array(
    'use_admin_layout' => true,
    'admin_layout_template' => 'layout/admin',
    // you could even define a login layout template here
    'login_layout_template' => 'layout/login',
),
```

Next in `MyZfcAdmin/Module.php` add a listener, almost exactly like the one in ZfcAdmin only have it check your `myzfcadmin` config values instead ...

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $em = $app->getEventManager();

    $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'selectLayoutBasedOnRoute'));
}

public function selectLayoutBasedOnRoute(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $sm = $app->getServiceManager();
    $config = $sm->get('config');

    if (false === $config['myzfcadmin']['use_admin_layout']) {
        return;
    }

    $match = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $controller = $e->getTarget();

    if (!$match instanceof \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch
        || 0 !== strpos($match->getMatchedRouteName(), 'zfcadmin')
        || $controller->getEvent()->getResult()->terminate()
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if ($controller instanceof \MyZfcAdmin\Controller\AdminController
        && $match->getParam('action') == 'login'
    ) {
        // if you'd rather just set the layout in your controller action just return here
        // return;
        // otherwise, use the configured login layout ..
        $layout = $config['myzfcadmin']['login_layout_template'];
    } else {
        $layout = $config['myzfcadmin']['admin_layout_template'];
    }

    $controller->layout($layout);                
}
```

As you can see, I added code to check the controller is your specific AdminController instance and login action, and if so, set the alternate template otherwise use the default, no need to worry about it in your controller now.

Comment: This approach worked for me. Is it really impossible to change layout with `$this->layout('layout/login');` ? :( This approach is big and monstrous :( Sure, I will use it and answer will be accepted but... :'(

Answer (score 1):

Add your layout in the template map of your view manager in the module.config.php

Like so:

```
// View file paths
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map'             => array
        'layout/login' => 'path_to_layout_file'
    )
)
```

Then, in your controller try setting the layout like this, using the setTemplate() method:

```
$layout = $this->layout();
$layout->setTemplate('layout/login');
```

EDIT, the following is code from the Zend library:

Inside `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Layout` notice this method:

```
/**
 * Invoke as a functor
 *
 * If no arguments are given, grabs the "root" or "layout" view model.
 * Otherwise, attempts to set the template for that view model.
 *
 * @param  null|string $template
 * @return Model|Layout
 */
public function __invoke($template = null)
{
    if (null === $template) {
        return $this->getViewModel();
    }
    return $this->setTemplate($template);
}
```

If you don't provide a template it will call this method:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the root view model from the event
 *
 * @return Model
 * @throws Exception\DomainException
 */
protected function getViewModel()
{
    $event     = $this->getEvent();
    $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($viewModel, true) . '</pre>';die;

    if (!$viewModel instanceof Model) {
        throw new Exception\DomainException('Layout plugin requires that event view model is populated');
    }
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Notice the `print_r` statement, if you look at it, it will show you this:

```
Zend\View\Model\ViewModel Object
(
[captureTo:protected] => content
[children:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[options:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[template:protected] => layout/layout
[terminate:protected] => 
[variables:protected] => Zend\View\Variables Object
    (
        [strictVars:protected] => 
        [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[append:protected] => 
)
```

Notice the `[template:protected] => layout/layout` that why I was saying I think Zend defaults to that layout.

So go into that file, in the `__invoke` method and do `echo $template;die;` when you are setting your layout with `$this->setTemplate('layout/login')` in your controller and see if its even getting passed there. Then you might be able to trace it better.

EDIT: Setting up multiple layouts.

Here is one way you could set up layouts for your modules in an effort to reduce the likelihood of a conflict or something being overwritten.

```
// where $sm is the service manager
$config = $sm->get('config');
$config = array_merge($config, include '/path_to_config/layouts.config.php');
if (isset($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace])) 
{
    $controller->layout($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace]);
}
```

And your layouts config could look something this:

```
'module_layouts' => array(
   '_default'   => 'layout/layout',
   'admin'      => 'layout/admin',
   'foo'        => 'layout/foo',
   'login'      => 'layout/login' // etc, etc
),
```

Comment: Just updated my answer with it. Going to try it again.

Comment: check the EDIT with the new code for the controller and see if that works for you.

Comment: 1 moment. I will try it.

Comment: Wait a bit :) I found another bug with routing. Just fixed it. Now going to try your code. Don't worry it will be accepted if it will help me :)

Comment: Updated answer with new code. Unfortunately, it didn't helped :(

Comment: Added link to the files on github, so you can review them by yourself.

Comment: I basically have similar code in a current ZF2 project and it's working fine. Maybe try commenting out where this default/parent layout is getting set, and see then if the login layout appears. If that happens, then it's getting overwritten somewhere. Worth a try at least.

Comment: I just tried to remove `'layout/layout'` definition from `module.config.php` file of Application module and whole layout is still working. Are you sure it must be defined? I am trying find layout/layout` in whole project (sure on files contents) and it can't find any definition of it.

Comment: + I am using module with its own layout (ZfcAdmin) and there are no definition of layout `layout/admin`.

Comment: i think if you don't specify a layout, then it uses the default. For example, I have several modules, and they use different layouts from a module layout config file, but if I remove that config, then they revert back to the default layout/layout. If I remove layout/layout then then I am presented with an error. I'll show some code in the Zend library one moment.

Comment: Well. Strange. I can't find anything with search in file contents in whole zf2 folder. I tried to find `layout/layout`. When I remove `layout/layout` definition in `module.config.php` file of Application module I don't get any errors. It looks like somewhere it is defined, but as I said, I tried to find it and I got nothing.

Comment: You know I am using ZendDevelopersTools and I can watch what configs were loaded. I am trying to find `layout/layout` in it after I removed `layout/layout` from Application config. I found nothing. And it is still working.

Comment: Anyway vote up. You are trying to help me. I updated my post with some debug results. LoL, I bet it is very simple mistake :(

Comment: Note, that if I use approach suggested in linked post, layout is set, but is not rendered. Why?

Comment: lol thanks for the upvote. Yea I'd say you're at least one step closer when it's returning `string(12) "layout/login"`. Maybe you can just keep tracing it from there, follow every method until you find where `layout/login` is being overwritten.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this too, but it is strange, that I need to trace function calls to change layout. I think there are some native method in zf2. I will try to debug layer, I am not at home now.

Comment: With new comments from Crisp it looks like, that ZfcAdmin layout was overwritten, as you said :) I hope, problem will be solved soon :). Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, hope you get it

Comment: You said, you have same code in your project and it is working. You are not using `ZfcAdmin` module, right?

Comment: No I don't have that module, but the application has about 3-4 modules all with different layouts and it's working fine. That is why I was saying I'm pretty sure it's being overwritten somewhere. Something to watch out for when using multiple modules/layouts.

Comment: See the latest edit: "EDIT: Setting up multiple layouts." After you find where it's being overwritten that might be a good way of defining your layouts for each module.

Comment: Hm :) Thanks! What if module has no specified layout in that config file?

Comment: I mean if layout is not specified in layout config file what layout will be rendered? `_default`?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav: There's already a module for per module layouts here -> https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts. It doesn't solve per controller or as in this case a per action layout requirement though. Nor does it stop zfcadmin from overwriting it when it's an admin route or conversely from the module layout overwriting the admin layout depending on layout listener priority.